# Saving docx files names and pdf files names into a txt file and copying those docx and pdf files into a specific folder

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx, python-os

I have a directory called found_files and a `txt` file called foundFile located into Users/PaCY/Downloads. I want to create a python script that saves docx file names and pdf file names into that txt file called foundFile and then copies those docx and pdf files into a directory called found_files.

this is the code below!

```
    import glob, os
    os.chdir("/Users/PaCY/Downloads")
    a = open("foundFile.txt", "w")
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/PaCY/Downloads/'):
    for filename in files:
    a.write(str(filename) + os.linesep)
```

PS: I'm running the program and getting the names of all files located in current working directory.

Anyone with the help on this program guys.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: then after writing the name of the file, you can move the file with `copyfile(".", "found_files") ` , just import `copyfile` from `shutil` with `from shutil import copyfile`

Comment: @BijayRegmi just done as you said and I am getting an error like this:                     
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: that means you dont have permission to write into the folder that want to copy the file to. Nothing wrong with the script itself.